# Ajax POST not working while GET is working fine in phonegap

Tags: ajax, web-services, post, cordova, soapui

Here is my code

```
$
.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type : 'POST',//While GET working
    async: false,
    url : "http://192.168.1.198:9051/something.xml" + "?time=" + Date.now(),
    data : {
        key : "value"
        },
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {
            },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

This is giving me error

for alert(xhr.status);-----------> 200

for alert(thrownError);----------> Error: Invalid XML

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out... I was passing some wrong xml as request...